# how to pass the value of a variable out from its loop in c

Tags: c, variables, loops

here i ask the user to input number:

```
do{
   printf("Enter cellphone number +63");
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(pb[i].cellphone);

 ///check if there is a similar number from the database
   for(r=0; r<i; r++){
      same = strcmp(pb[i].cellphone, pb[r].cellphone);
      if(same==0){
         printf("Number is same with contact no. %d\n", r+1);
       }
   }


 /// at this point the value of same is becoming nonzero and continues to the next code. 

}while(!isdigit(*pb[i].cellphone)||same == 0);
```

my goal is if the user input a non unique number it will ask gain the user to input a new number.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: You are not allowed to use `fflush` on an input stream. Also don't ever use `gets` as you can't implement a protection against an overflow.

Comment: What's the problem? What do you expect, what do you get? Any errors?

Comment: if it not find unique number then it will already again ask from loop and is you cellphone number in char?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you really want to use `isdigit` this way, as it probably doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exit the `for` loop or `same` will get overwritten in the next loop iteration:

```
do {
   printf("Enter cellphone number +63");
   fflush(stdout);     // Flush stdout so that text is shown (needed because the printf doesn't end with a newline and stdout is line buffered)
   gets(pb[i].cellphone);

 ///check if there is a similar number from the database
   for (r=0; r<i; r++){
      same = strcmp(pb[i].cellphone, pb[r].cellphone);
      if (same==0){
         printf("Number is same with contact no. %d\n", r+1);
         break;  // Exit the loop. Otherwise same will be overwritten in next iteration
      }
   }
} while(!isdigit(*pb[i].cellphone) || same == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int find_num(char *phone, int i, phones *phones) {
  int r;
  for(r=0; r<i; r++){
      if (!strcmp(phone, pb[r].cellphone))
        return r;
  }
  return -1;
}

while (1) {
   printf("Enter cellphone number +63");
   fflush(stdin);
   gets(pb[i].cellphone);
   same = find_num(pb[i].cellphone, i, pb);
   if (same == -1) break;
   printf("Number is same with contact no. %d\n", same+1);        
}
```